# Require.js + AngularAMD - Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'loginController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angular-amd

I have looked through all the similar questions I can find but none was helpful in resolving this error:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'loginController' is not a function, got undefined.

Below are my files:

LoginController.js

```
"use strict";
    define(['app-config', 'loginService'], function (app) {
    app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$location', 'loginService',
        function (sc, loc, loginService) {

            sc.login = function () {

              console.log("Email Address = " + sc.EmailAddress);
              console.log("Password = " + sc.Password);
            }

    }]);
```

app-config.js

```
"use strict";
define(['angularAMD', 'angular-route', 'angular-resource'], function (angularAMD) {
var app = angular.module("openInterviewApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
           /* .when('/login', angularAMD.route({

                templateUrl: 'Accounts/Login.html',
                controllerUrl: 'Accounts/LoginController'
            })) */
            .when("/:section/:tree", angularAMD.route({

                templateUrl: function (rp) { return rp.section + '/' + rp.tree + '.html'; },

                resolve: {

                    load: ['$q', '$rootScope', '$location', function ($q, $rootScope, $location) {

                        var path = $location.path();
                        var parsePath = path.split("/");
                        var parentPath = parsePath[1];
                        var controllerName = parsePath[2];

                        var loadController = parentPath + "/" + controllerName + "Controller";
                        console.log ("loadController=" + loadController);

                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        require([loadController], function () {
                            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                                deferred.resolve();
                            });
                        });
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }]
                }

            }))
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

    }]);

angularAMD.bootstrap(app);

return app;
});
```

main.js

```
require.config({

//By default load any module IDs from baseUrl
//baseUrl is normally set to the same directory as the script used in a data-main attribute
baseUrl: "",

// paths config is relative to the baseUrl
// never includes a ".js" extension since the paths config could be for a directory.
// ex: app: 'app' means if the module ID starts with "app", load it from the /app directory
paths: {
    'app-config': 'scripts/app-config',
    'angular': 'scripts/angular-1.3.15',
    'angular-route': 'scripts/angular-route-1.3.15',
    'angular-resource': 'scripts/angular-resource-1.3.15',
    'angularAMD': 'scripts/angularAMD-4.13.2015',
    'jquery': 'scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min',
    'loginService': 'services/loginService'
},

// Add angular modules that does not support AMD out of the box, put it in a shim
shim: {
    'angularAMD': ['angular'],
    'angular-route': ['angular'],    //angular-route depends on angular module
    'angular-resource': ['angular']
},

// kick start application
deps: ['app-config']
});
```

Login.html

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="LoginController" ng-cloak>
```

loginService.js

```
define(['app-config'], function (app) {

app.factory('loginService', ['$resource',
function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        'jbossews-1.0/login',
        {}, {
        login: { method: 'POST', cache: false, isArray: false }
    });
}]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller should like this,Try this

```
"use strict";
define(['app-config', 'loginService'], function (app) {
    app.register.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$location', 'loginService',
        function (sc, loc, loginService) {
            console.log("LoginController calling");
            sc.login = function () {
                console.log("Email Address = " + sc.EmailAddress);
                console.log("Password = " + sc.Password);
            };
        }]);
});
```

and loginService.js should be like this

```
define(['app-config'], function (app) {

app.register.factory('loginService', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
      return $resource(
          'jbossews-1.0/login',
          {}, {
          login: { method: 'POST', cache: false, isArray: false }
      });
  }]);
});
```

**Note:** This is something which you are missing, Let me try to explain here in more detail.(Considering you have a basic knowledge of require and angularAMD)

> Controllers and services in the application rely on RequireJS to
>   access the object representing the application’s module and then
>   access the register property to register a controller script with
>   AngularJS.
>
> This type of registration is required since using the standard
>   angular.module(“ModuleName”).controller() code won’t work properly
>   with dynamically loaded controller scripts.
>
> RequireJS’s define() function to get to the app object and then uses
>   it to register the controller.
>
> The app.register.controller() function points to AngularJS’s
>   $controllerProvider.register() function behind the scenes with app.js.
>
> All of the controllers,services in the application follow this
>   pattern.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but when I tried your suggested code above, I got this error: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: loginServiceProvider <- loginService <- LoginController.

Comment: @cig Oops. It was typo. Check my edited code and try It will work.

Comment: If I added your code, with "app.register.controller", I get this error: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: loginServiceProvider <- loginService <- LoginController.  BUT if I used my original code of "app.controller", I got this error: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'LoginController' is not a function, got undefined.  (I think that is the only difference between your code and mine, right?)

Comment: Here you need to register service also like "app.register.factory"

Comment: That is it. Adding "register" to both files.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: It definitely helped and I accepted it, but it requires 15 reputation to up vote it, and I am a newbie to this site and don't seem to have enough reputation points to do that.  :(

Comment: @cig Check my edited answer. It will help you to understand more of your mistake.